# Time series data is not stationary after differencing?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, time-series, statsmodels

I have some timeseries data as below. I know that this is not stationary & running it through the dickey fuller test, I get 0.99. Which is good.

```
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
x = [5, 7, 9,13,11,12,14,17,14,16,15,12,11,15,19,17,21,23,27,25,29,31,33,31,37,35,34,31,39,40,42,41,43,42,44]
df_test = adfuller(x, autolag = "AIC")
```

But, once I difference the dataset, it still does not have a p-value of <0.05 (it's 0.12).

```
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
x = [2,2,4,-2,1,2,3,-3,2,-1,-3,-1,4,4,-2,4,2,4,-2,4,2,2,-2,6,-2,-1,-3,8,1,2,-1,2,-1,2]
df_test = adfuller(x, autolag = "AIC")
```

Here is the data I am using, what am I doing wrong here?

```
Day,value,Difference
mon ,5,
tue,7,2
wed,9,2
thu,13,4
fri,11,-2
sat,12,1
sun,14,2
mon ,17,3
tue,14,-3
wed,16,2
thu,15,-1
fri,12,-3
sat,11,-1
sun,15,4
mon ,19,4
tue,17,-2
wed,21,4
thu,23,2
fri,27,4
sat,25,-2
sun,29,4
mon ,31,2
tue,33,2
wed,31,-2
thu,37,6
fri,35,-2
sat,34,-1
sun,31,-3
mon ,39,8
tue,40,1
wed,42,2
thu,41,-1
fri,43,2
sat,42,-1
sun,44,2
```

Also, here is the before and after differencing:
[image]

Comment: Differencing once doesn't guarantee to yield a stationary series. You might want to difference one more time if you are unsatisfied.

Comment: ADF tests also have low power, so with a short time series it can be difficult to reject the null even if the series is stationary.  An eyeball check suggests that the difference is in fact stationary.